# Mystery connections at login - how to find out what's responsible?

Tags: fedora, gnome, kde, background-process, internet

I have two connections that occur every single time I login (GUI KDE). They disappear after about one minute. I want to know what they're telling who.

So to get started, how do you take connections found by **ss -rt**:

```
    ESTAB          0               0                            DESKTOP:45746                   ec2-54-184-13-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https
    ESTAB          0               0                            DESKTOP:45748                   ec2-54-184-13-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https
```

and find the process that reaches out or illicit's a response from those hosts?

I already took issue with geoclue and disabled that. There's also Fedora project and Gnome/KDE servers(depending what I want when I log in) that handle crash reports, or some kind of telemetry and unknown others. However I have observed where those are usually communicating and these AWS hosts aren't familiar.

All I want is a quiet start-up but without having to disable the nic before every reboot and shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-p` to get the name of the process making that connection, i.e., `ss -rtp`.